# WordPress Rest API Response Count

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, api

I have WordPress Rest API used to retrieve all the users.
https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/users/#list-users.
my Wordpress site contains more than 10 users. But here response contains only 4 users.

how to retrieve all the user?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Mani c

Comment: as per documentation: *The REST API exposed user data for all users who had authored a post of a public post type. WordPress 4.7.1 limits this to only post types which have specified that they should be shown within the REST API.*

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest method is to use **Pagination**
for example - if you wanted to retrieve 20 users

```
yourdomain/wp-json/wp/v2/users?per_page=20
```

[click more information on pagination](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/pagination/)